# Can I cut the trees from the middle?

Tags: cuttings, privacy-plants

I live in New Brunswick, where my backyard is filled with trees that have grown into natural, unique shapes.

These trees provide me with privacy from my neighbors, particularly at the lower parts, **but** they also block the sun in my garden. Another issue I have that many of them fell down this winter and they are not stable.

I'm considering cutting them from the middle to maintain privacy and sunlight. However, I'm worried that they might die after being cut.

Does anyone have advice or other suggestions for me?

[image: cut line, many trees fall on my garden]

Comment: The trees will figure it out, but cutting conifers in half will never be pretty. Evergreens cannot later generate symmetry.

Comment: If you want a hedge, plant things that take hedge-trimming style cuts well. White cedar would be a good choice for the location. Spruce/fir, not so much. To maintain a dense bottom, make the hedge cuts for a wider base and narrower top, so it all gets sun. Vertical hedges tend to get thin on the bottom due to lack of sun. As for topping trees without specialized equipment and experience, it's a great way to die; and they grow funny afterwards, as Kevin's answer mentions.

Answer (score 4):

I don't recommend cutting them in half.  What will happen to the birches is that they will sprout one or more headers.  The conifers will do the same to a lesser degree.  From [here](https://extension.unh.edu/blog/2021/02/can-water-sprouts-suckers-be-prevented-trees)

> When trees are stressed or have suffered some sort of trauma, they
> often respond by producing upright shoots called water sprouts and
> suckers.

This sounds positive but the sucker growth is not as strongly attached. After a number of years the growth above the sprout can get heavy and will tear off in a wind storm.

What I do recommend is thinning.  Cut and chip the ones that have fallen over and do the same to the weakest candidates that are upright.  Put the wood chips in a quarter inch thick layer where the trees are as mulch.

By removing the weakest ones you will encourage seedlings to grow and allow more light without having to do a lot of work halfway up a tree.